# How can remove wrapline while buffering with sf package in r

Tags: r, buffer, geospatial, r-sf, r-raster

How can I remove the crossing line while using the buffer code below. I tried to create buffers round some point locations and to have a union but ended up getting a crossline.

Please see the codes below

```
library(raster)
library(sf)
```

```
bioc1 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=10) # load world raster files
bio1 <- bioc1[[1]] # select the file raster
plot(bio1) # examine the raster
ebio <- extent(c(-208.341377620,194.932040093,-50.879788320,41.18930971)) # the extent for the points

set.seed(120)
df<- sampleRandom(x=bio1, size=10000, na.rm=TRUE, ext=ebio, xy=TRUE) #generate random point in the prefered extent
df<- data.frame(df)

df.sf4236 <- sf::st_as_sf(df, coords=c("x", "y"), crs=raster::crs(bio1)) #change to sf to allow buffering
plot(bio1)
plot(df.sf4236, add=TRUE)

# reproject before buffering to enable buffereing in meters
eckertIV <- "+proj=eck4 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"
df.sf54012 <- sf::st_transform(df.sf4236, crs = eckertIV)
# buffer the point with 1500 000 meters
df.buf <- sf::st_buffer(df.sf54012, dist = 2000000) %>% 
  sf::st_union() %>% 
  sf::st_sf() %>%
  sf::st_transform(crs = raster::crs(bio1))

plot(bio1)
plot(df.sf4236, add=TRUE)
# To add sf objects to a plot, use add = TRUE
plot(df.buf, border = "red", lwd = 3, add = TRUE)
```

Output from the code
[obtained_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YreCx.png)

Expect results
[expected_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsCyv.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.